# How to receive protobuf messages sent by the Foxglove server and then save them as MCAP?

Tags: protocol-buffers, foxglove-studio, mcap

I have customized some protobufs, processed them on the server using C++, and published them through the localhost port using the Foxglove server. I hope to save these messages as mcap files for playback with Foxglove.

Is this attempt feasible, or is there a more common method to save custom protobufs as mcap files?

I have made the following attempts:

1.Installed mcap on the server, but encountered environment issues.
2. Used Foxglove websocket locally to receive information and then saved it using mcap, but did not find relevant tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`mcap-record` example client](https://github.com/foxglove/ws-protocol/tree/main/typescript/ws-protocol-examples#example-clients) to do this, for example:

```bash
$ npx @foxglove/ws-protocol-examples@latest mcap-record ws://localhost:8765 -o <file.mcap>
```

It should also be possible to use the [mcap libraries](https://github.com/foxglove/mcap) on the server to record MCAP directly. Please [start an issue or discussion](https://github.com/foxglove/mcap/issues/new/choose) or [join us in Slack](https://foxglove.dev/slack) to report any problems you encounter with using these libraries.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have joined Slack and will test this solution as soon as possible. And will provide specific feedback if it can be executed.